How can I use pinch gesture when testing an iphone app featuring google maps inside TestFlight on MacOS?
I am testing a mobile app, in Android and iOS. When running on iOS Simulator or Android Simulator, it's easy to simulate a pinch movement just holding a modifier Key, like Shift, Command, etc. No problem here.
However when I want to test the same app, the release prebuild version, using TestFlight running on a Macbook, how can I simulate the the pinch gesture, to get a zoom in/out effect?

I just got it.
If I double click on the map, and immediately after the second click, start dragging down the pointer to zoom in and dragging up to zoom out.
